# Self join looping in view?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have an dataset, which seems to function like it should be (under):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Collaboration] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18
                [parent_id] => 
                [created] => 2012-01-14 20:17:00
                [title] => Title 1
                [message] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet major 1.
                [type] => Competition
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 100
                        [parent_id] => 18
                        [created] => 2012-02-29 14:07:23
                        [title] => Title sub 1
                        [message] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sub 1.
                        [type] => Message 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 101
                        [parent_id] => 18
                        [created] => 2012-02-29 14:07:23
                        [title] => Title sub 2
                        [message] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sub 2.
                        [type] => Message
                    )

            )

        [Registration] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Collaboration] => Array
            (...
```

What is the way that I could render this self join dataset in view? I can see data this way

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $collaboration['Collaboration'][0]['message'];?></td>           
        </tr>
</table>
```

but of course it is not the ways this arrays should be used. How to loop thru this inner array?

Thanks,

Comment: That array structure seems very unusual. Where's that coming from, what query produces it?

Answer (score 0):

Model is:

```
var $hasMany = array('Registration','Collaboration' => array('foreignKey' => 'parent_id'));
```

and controller:

```
function message_board() {
$this->paginate['Collaboration'] = array(
'conditions' 
=> array('Collaboration.to_name' => array('Extranet', 'Internet'), 'AND' 
=> array('Collaboration.company_id' => Configure::read('company'), 'AND' 
=> array('Collaboration.parent_id' => null))),
'limit' => 10,
'order' => 'Collaboration.created DESC'
);
```

and table is:

```
id               int(11) PK
parent_id        int(11)
created          datetime
title            varchar(1000)
message          longtext...
```

// Jari